# WPF MVVM prevent a Expander control to collapse

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

Is there a possibility to prevent a `Expander control` in `WPF` to `collapse`, when certain `conditions` are given. For my usecase it is not possible to do it directly in the `xaml`, because whether the `Expander` can be collapsed or not depends on condition just known during run time.

Its no option for me to use an event, because the project is a `test project` to `seperate gui` and code strictly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can bind to the IsExpanded property.

For example you can use a DataTrigger, MultiDataTrigger, ValueConverter, or MultiValueConverter to manage the data binding to the IsExpanded property.

There's also a interesting article [here](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/28/wpf-making-a-expander-look-like-a-groupbox/) that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the Expander to always remain toggle-on. Just leaving it here.

```
    <Expander IsExpanded="True"></Expander>
```

Comment: This will allow it to default to open but will not prevent it from functioning normally. It will still collapse and expand after loading.